# Connection fails on Nats for K3S Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, k3s, nats.io

Goal: Running Nats containerized in K3S on a cluster of Raspberry Pis, with Nats to communicate between several applications.
I have been following these guides: https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/nats-kubernetes and https://dev.to/karanpratapsingh/nats-at-edge-with-k3s-5377. In both cases, I have been using helm to install and run Nats service.

Problem: Nats times out whenever I am trying to run tests inside deployment/nats-k3s-box, yielding the following error: "nats: error: dial tcp: lookup my-nats: i/o timeout". I have tried both methods to try to test if the Nats service, which yield the following results.

```
kubectl exec -n default -it deployment/my-nats-box -- /bin/sh -l
             _             _
 _ __   __ _| |_ ___      | |__   _____  __
| '_ \ / _` | __/ __|_____| '_ \ / _ \ \/ /
| | | | (_| | |_\__ \_____| |_) | (_) >  <
|_| |_|\__,_|\__|___/     |_.__/ \___/_/\_\

nats-box v0.13.0
my-nats-box-b864cbd4c-46q2z:~# nats sub test&
my-nats-box-b864cbd4c-46q2z:~# nats sub test &
my-nats-box-b864cbd4c-46q2z:~# nats pub test hi
nats: error: dial tcp: lookup my-nats: i/o timeout
nats: error: dial tcp: lookup my-nats: i/o timeout
nats: error: dial tcp: lookup my-nats: i/o timeout
[2]+  Done(1)                    nats sub test
[1]+  Done(1)                    nats sub test
my-nats-box-b864cbd4c-46q2z:~#
my-nats-box-b864cbd4c-46q2z:~# nats: error: dial tcp: lookup my-nats: i/o timeout
/bin/sh: nats:: not found
my-nats-box-b864cbd4c-46q2z:~# nats bench test --msgs=10000000 --pub 5 --sub 2
14:50:13 Starting Core NATS pub/sub benchmark [subject=test, multisubject=false, multisubjectmax=0, msgs=10,000,000, msgsize=128 B, pubs=5, subs=2, pubsleep=0s, subsleep=0s]
nats: error: nats connection 0 failed: dial tcp: lookup my-nats: i/o timeout
my-nats-box-b864cbd4c-46q2z:~#
```

Kubectl get all looks like this:

```
 kubectl get all
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/my-nats-0                             3/3     Running   0          2m47s
pod/my-nats-box-b864cbd4c-46q2z           1/1     Running   0          2m47s
pod/server-pod                            1/1     Running   0          6d15h
pod/server-pods-veibox-7489b7bb94-8mv7d   1/1     Running   0          3d1h
pod/server-pods-veibox-7489b7bb94-k949q   1/1     Running   0          3d1h
pod/server-pods-veibox-7489b7bb94-rk4ts   1/1     Running   0          3d1h

NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                 AGE
service/kubernetes           ClusterIP   10.43.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                                                 51d
service/my-nats              ClusterIP   None           <none>        4222/TCP,6222/TCP,8222/TCP,7777/TCP,7422/TCP,7522/TCP   2m47s
service/server-pods-veibox   ClusterIP   10.43.214.43   <none>        80/TCP                                                  3d1h

NAME                                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/my-nats-box          1/1     1            1           2m47s
deployment.apps/server-pods-veibox   3/3     3            3           3d1h

NAME                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/my-nats-box-b864cbd4c           1         1         1       2m47s
replicaset.apps/server-pods-veibox-7489b7bb94   3         3         3       3d1h

NAME                       READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/my-nats   1/1     2m47s
```

And the logs also don't seem to be giving me any problems

```
kubectl logs service/my-nats
Defaulted container "nats" out of: nats, reloader, metrics
[7] 2022/09/26 14:47:58.528353 [INF] Starting nats-server
[7] 2022/09/26 14:47:58.528624 [INF]   Version:  2.9.0
[7] 2022/09/26 14:47:58.528633 [INF]   Git:      [517d9b3]
[7] 2022/09/26 14:47:58.528640 [INF]   Name:     my-nats-0
[7] 2022/09/26 14:47:58.528647 [INF]   ID:       NC2QJKIVXAW3HAJA6DI6QXXAN72P6ZYEZRUNM5PHDOTSSQZS753DJBYJ
[7] 2022/09/26 14:47:58.528683 [INF] Using configuration file: /etc/nats-config/nats.conf
[7] 2022/09/26 14:47:58.530977 [INF] Starting http monitor on 0.0.0.0:8222
[7] 2022/09/26 14:47:58.531242 [INF] Listening for client connections on 0.0.0.0:4222
[7] 2022/09/26 14:47:58.531880 [INF] Server is ready
```

What have I been doing wrong with my installation of Nats, and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: I'm not alone :D
---
@Johnney, Did you try with `telnet`? I'm having very similar problem - my application is usually failing (but sometimes succeeding) in connecting to the NATS cluster, and I can't identify the reason.
But when I `telnet` into the NATS cluster from a debug pod I *always* succeed. I'm following https://docs.nats.io/reference/reference-protocols/nats-protocol-demo.

Interestingly enough, `telnet` works with `demo.nats.io` and with the k8s service IP, but *not* with the k8s service DNS name, and I don't have other DNS issues with other k8s applications in the cluster.